# cookies set by server doesn't get shown in javascript first time

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I really don't know what the deal is. I set up my cookies in php:

```
$locale = 'en_US';
setcookie('locale', $locale);
```

And I access it in Javascript:

```
console.log(document.cookie);
```

weirdly this doesn't show the cookies. However, if I open the browser console and type `document.cookie`, it shows all the cookies.

And if I refresh the page, the cookies get shown.

For some reason, cookies don't get sent to the browser when they are set.

Are cookies being stored at the end of the response? If yes, how can I make it, so that they are stored at the beginning?

Comment: Are you setting the cookie before any output in your php?

Comment: Yes. Before there is anything at all. I am sure cookies cannot be sent if there is any output anyways.

Comment: On the first time (when cookies don't load) look in the network tab and click on the page being loaded. In the response headers, is there a set-cookie?

Comment: There are no response cookies. What is the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code just worked for me in Chrome, obviously within the same request

```
$locale = 'unique_number_to_differntiate_from_yours'; 
setcookie('different_cookie_name', $locale);
echo "<script> console.log(document.cookie); </script>";
exit ;
```

As pointed by Davin H , you need to ensure there is no output before you call setcookie , not even a space.  The reason is that cookies are set using headers, and headers can not be set once you have output started.

Comment: I am going to check a little bit more and see where the problem is

Comment: There is no output before the cookies before I added them even before the headers. I am going to check your code in another environment where there is no other code that can interfere with it

Comment: Ok I found the problem. The cookies were not being sent because I made an error in my code where the cookies were only being sent during ajax call